# Using EXIFTool to add EXIF data from filenames

Tags: scripting, perl, filenames, exif, cpan

There is a set of photos with timestamps in their filenames like these:

```
Photo on 3-09-12 at 9.24 PM #2.jpg

Photo on 3-09-12 at 9.24 PM #1.jpg

Photo on 3-09-12 at 8.23 PM.jpg
```

etc.

("3-09-12", means "3rd Sep 2012" or DD-MM-YY)

But these photos have no EXIF data at all. Before you imported them to a larger collection, how would you pipe this information to `exiftool` and also tell it to add new timestamps as EXIF data, all from the photos' filenames?

***Update***: (The now Pt. 1 of) my question about parsing filenames with DD-MM-YY and 12 hour time has been very kindly answered by @Stephane. But I discovered that the  same batch of photos contains filenames with one variation I had missed. I hope it makes more sense to add a 'Pt. 2' instead of starting a whole new question.

**In short**:

How could I change @Stephane's brilliant answer --

```
exiftool '-CreateDate<${FileName;use Date::Manip;
                      Date_Init("DateFormat=non-US");
                      /on (.*?at.*?[AP]M)/;$_=$1;
                      y/./:/;$_=UnixDate($_,"%Y-%m-%d %T")
                      }' ./*on\ *at*[PA]M*.jpg
```

-- so that it might work with filename format below, which is slightly different from the first part of the question, in that it uses YYYY-MM-DD and 24-hour time:

```
Photo on 2010-09-15 at 18.44 #4.jpg

Photo on 2010-09-15 at 18.44 #3.jpg

Photo on 2010-09-15 at 18.44.jpg
```

**More explanation:**

Trying to edit the `Date::Manip` part of the Stephane's script seems to show up my ignorance of what's going on in the most important parts of it.

I tried omitting the `Date_Init` line since we are back to an ISO-esque full-year date format and then having

```
/on (.*?at.*?)/;$_=$1;
y/./:/;$_=UnixDate($_,"%Y-%m-%d %T")
' ./*on\ *at*.jpg
```

But `exiftool` is giving me `no writeable tags` and `FileName not defined`. Instructions at http://search.cpan.org/~sbeck/Date-Manip-5.56/lib/Date/Manip.pod don't seem to be helpful (at least to me) in understanding what's going on with those periods, that 'y' at the start of the line, semicolon etc, and they're rather ungoogleable :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
exiftool '-CreateDate<${FileName;use Date::Manip;
                      Date_Init("DateFormat=non-US");
                      /on (.*at.*?)(?: #\d+)?\.jpg$/;$_=$1;
                      y/./:/;$_=UnixDate($_,"%Y-%m-%d %T")
                      }' ./*on\ *at*.jpg
```

(you may have to install the `Date::Manip` `perl` module).

The `-Tag<value` sets the corresponding tag. The `${tag;perl-code}` can be used to expand to the value of `tag` after it has been processed by the `perl-code`.

Here, the plan is to use `Date::Manip`'s `UnixDate` function to parse the date in the filename and convert it to a format acceptable for the `CreateDate` tag (`2011-04-15 21:38:00`).

`Date::Manip` understands a lot of common date formats. For instance, it understands `3-09-12 at 9:24 PM` (though you have to tell it whether it's the US or non-US convention where the day or month is first) and `2010-09-15 at 18.44` (note the `:` instead of `.`).

So what we do is extract that part from the filename, convert the `.` to `:` and pass it to `UnixDate`.

Comment: For any interested Mac users, I fixed ExifTool's not seeing `p5.8-datemanip` by **getting rid of the generic version from ExifTool's homepage and replacing it with MacPorts' version**. Remove it: `sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/exiftool /usr/bin/lib`. Then do `sudo port install p5.8-image-exiftool`. Obviously, you also need to have MacPorts' `p5.8-datemanip` and `perl5.8`. Then new ExifTool executable is `exiftool-5.8`.

Comment: Stephane, just realised that editing your script to accept the format "3-09-12" as "3rd Sep 2012" is going to be rather complicated. Do you know which part of the Date::Manip manual I should be looking at, or would you know offhand how to change the script appropriately? :)

Comment: @iceequal, see edit. Note that if using MacPorts, I suppose you don't have to use such an antique perl version, exiftool works well with 5.18.

Comment: Oof, just discovered another (separate) batch of photos created by the same program but with, for some reason, a slightly different format: `Photo on 2011-04-15 at 21.38 #3.jpg` and `Photo on 2010-09-15 at 18.42` etc. Would you have any idea about those? Or is there a good link that might explain some of `Date::Manip`’s functions for beginners?

Comment: @iceequal `Date::Manip` will handle those out of the box. You just need to adapt the regexp that extracts the date+time from the filename. See the edit.